# Java compile expected public class error

Tags: javascript, java, compiler-errors, javac, editplus

```
class  
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

while compiling it was showing error

```
---------- Compile ----------
Untitled1.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
public class  
            ^
1 error

Output completed (0 sec consumed) - Normal Termination
```

Comment: you know the class needs a name dont you??

Comment: and java aint js

Comment: Incidentally, your error message shows `public` but your code example doesn't.

Comment: Java has no relationship to javascript. Please remove the javascript tag and from the title. Tag-spamming is discouraged here.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the name of the class:

```
public class MyFirstClass
// Here -----^
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Note that a public class' name must match the name of the file that declares it.

Comment: Thanks compiling now